# Dynamics of HtmlHelper Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I'm accustomed to extension methods being presented by intellisense, after the 'this' type is keyed-in.  But when I try this with HtmlHelper, the extension methods don't show - even though the 'using' statement is present.  Why is this?  To clarify, I'm doing this test from within a regular .cs file, rather than a .cshtml file.  No good reason, I'm simply playing with the MVC namespace and language to "see how it ticks."  I still don't know why the intellisense doesn't pick up all 4000 extensions (I exagerate, but there are many).

Speaking of thousands of extensions, why are these helper routines provided as extension methods?  If typical static classes had been used, probably a sample razor signature would be:

```
@EditorExtensions.EditorFor<T>(...)
```

Seems doable, and the "Framework Design Guidelines" states that extensions should seldom be used, and preferably:

1. only against interface types.
2. only on types that cannot be re-deployed

It doesn't seem that any of the extension method "criteria" applies.  This is why I would have expected regular static classes, with static methods to fill this roll.  What was the rationale?

**Update:** Sample code of a non-extension helper (for further discussion)

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Go(HtmlHelper foo){
        foo.Raw("Hello");
        return new MvcHtmlString("<p>What's up Doc</p>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why IntelliSense is not showing `HtmlHelper` extension methods for you. Are you sure you are `using System.Web.Mvc.Html`?

The reason why these helpers were implemented as extension methods is because they often need to have access to various state associated with the request, the model, etc. It's a lot more difficult to achieve this goal while still making the helpers unit-testable if they were implemented as static methods.

Comment: I'm curious about the unit-testing comment.  I've updated my question to include a code sample that I just now executed from a razor page.  The only difference between this custom static helper, and an extension method custom static helper, is the 'this' parameter keyword.  In short, I don't see how a non-extension method helper is any more difficult to unit-test.  Either way, both are ultimately static methods.  More thoughts?

Comment: Yes, they're both static methods. But the [`HtmlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=VS.98).aspx) parameter is what carries all the state information which the implementation of the static method can then use. This combined with the tersely named properties on the page classes allows you to write `@Html.Helper("value")` instead of `@StaticHelpers.Helper(Html, "value")`

Comment: At this point, I suspect the rationale was twofold: (1) it was a workaround to avoid having a god-object class, and (2) it has more consise syntax - as you've pointed out.  I'm guessing there was no further rationale.